# Client-Side Image Manipulation (Cropping)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, image-manipulation, jcrop

I am building a web application using **Parse** as my backend.

Part of the signup process involves the user uploading and cropping an image before I pass it along to my database (the picture is part of the user profile, similar to what you would do on Twitter).

I have figured out the uploading parts (both to the browser and then to the database), but I am not as confident with allowing the user to manipulate the image.

Most solutions involve using **jCrop** to achieve a result similar to the example [here](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop) (although without the PHP).

*Given that I am using Parse, is there a client-side solution that works better?  How might a solution look?*

Thanks!

Jesse

Comment: Why not using jCrop? As far as I see it is a clinet-side solution... EDIT: ahh I get it on my own, It only calculates the cropping and doesn't perform it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically I would go this way:

1. Load your image into a `<canvas>`
2. Crop the Image: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/
3. Save a image from the canvas: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

[Here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/) is a very good tutorial.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this yet, but I heard that this way work.

Also use `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:contain;` to get around nasty dimension problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can able to crop an image using HTML canvas, but it involves lots of codes, Consider using Cropperjs, It's a pure javascript library for cropping images. Here [client-side image cropping by cropperjs](https://www.adminspress.com/onex/view/UbOxMu) is the working example.